# Internal error: Symbol file with package cannot be empty

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm developing a Firebase app. After adding Firebase Firestore library, this Error Shows Up.

I already tried to clean the project and relocated it but nothing.

Comment: Try updating your android studio and SDK also all dependencies of your project with the latest versions.

Comment: Try to update your android studio and related build script of your project with the latest versions.

Comment: @NishikantoSarkarSimul Thank You.i Just Removed the firestore dependency but the error still exists.my android studio is updated.

Comment: @BelbaharRaouf Thank You.I Already tried